# What is the purpose of faded text in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS code (for my Javascript file), the text sometimes fades when I edit my code. Does anyone know what this means? I have researched it online, but can't find its purpose. I know arguments and variables in functions fade out until they are written in the function, but I haven't seen it before for entire functions.

I've included all my installed extensions in the picture in case one of these is doing the fade. I can also include all my code if I did not provide enough information. Thank you!

Edit: to clarify, the faded text I am speaking of is the entire function `placeInTable(y,x)` I am not speaking of the commented code.

[image]

Comment: Usually means unused or unreachable.

Comment: The function itself is probably not used at all.

Comment: Thank you! Okay this makes sense now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: answered about the commented part first, not reading the entire question

The function is faded because it hasn't been called, so no actions inside it have been executed.

Comment: Thank you! I should have clarified my question. I understand comments in code, however I didn't understand why the placeInTable function was faded (and is not commented out). I edited my original question :)

Comment: Also, it appears that the faded functions just weren't being used/reached in my code.

Comment: Sorry, I've answered the wrong question for the first time @BerkleyOlmstead